# Запись в файл для всех файлов проекта

Tags: c++

Друзья, помогите с задачей.
Как сделать так, чтобы запись в файл производилась из всех файлов проекта(например .cpp).

А то я объявляю в main.cpp - ofstream fout("__.txt"), fout<<"123";

И если пишу в другом файле(например qwerty.cpp)fout<<"privet";-то выводит ошибку
Подскажете?

Comment: Покажите код, так будет проще.

Comment: В `main.cpp` вам нужно объявить глобальную переменную `fout`. А во всех остальных файлах объявить ее внешней (extern).

Comment: Если вам нужно для логов, то стоит обратить внимание на сторонние либы, например `Google glog`

Comment: хочу попытаться сделать так, чтобы я мог записать что-нибудь в текстовый файл в другом .сpp файле(не в main.cpp). Смотрел форумы, всё указывает на создание заголовочных файлов, а потом прописать название заголовочного файла в файлы .cpp. Файл создается, но он пустой, ничего не записывается в него.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cpp
//qwerty.cpp
#include <fstream>

//std::ofstream fout; // ошибка многократного определения, 
                      // т.к. переменная определяется как глобальная, 
                      // но в файле main.cpp также есть определение глобальной 
                      // переменной с этим именем. Чтобы ошибка не возникла нужно только объявить 
                      // переменную не определяя её, для этого используется ключевое слово extern.

extern std::ofstream fout; // объявление переменной без определеня.
                           // Указывает, что переменная определена в другом месте.

// fout << "privet"; // ошибка, т.к. функции(в данном случае operator<<) 
                     // нужно вызывать из другой функции(например в main)

void write()
{
    fout << "123";
}
```

```cpp
//main.cpp
#include <fstream>
std::ofstream fout; // Определение глобальной переменной.
                    // Нужно, чтобы иметь возможность работать с ней из другого файла.

void write(); // Чтобы вызвать функцию определенную в другом файле, нужно перед этим объявить её.
              // Слово extern c функциями не используется, так как компилятор в состоянии отличить
              // определение от объявления по наличию или отсутствию тела функции.

int main()
{
    fout.open("__.txt");

    write();

    fout.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Открытие файла в глобальном конструкторе. Куда мы катимся?